# Convert form input's to [MyId,Form] using regex

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I have some large forms & instead of converting these forms to emails by hand I thought it would be faster if I could just search & replace using Dreamweavers RegEx functions -http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt1.html

Basically, I have some input values that I need to pull the input id's from & make into a value like [MyId,Form]

**EXAMPLE INPUT:**

```
<input name="PreviousReading100" id="PreviousReading100" type="number" style="width:200px; color:#666;" class="clear-default ForceNumber html5" value="[|PreviousReading100]" />
```

**RESULT REQUIRED:**

[PreviousReading100,Form]

**--HAVE TRIED--**

**FIND:**

```
<input\b(?=((?!(/>|id="?[0-9a-zA-Z]*")).)*id="?[0-9a-zA-Z]*").*?/>
```

**REPLACE:**

```
[$2,Form]
```

**RESULT:**

```
[id="PreviousReading100",Form]
```

Comment: Your example is not clear. In the required result, where does Form come from ? What field do you take ? id ? Why do you take only the 1st input in your example ? Is it always the case for each line ? for each form ? Finally ... What regex have you already tried ?

Comment: what language do you need this in?

Comment: @DanielA.White it's JS RegExp actually because Dreamweaver is using that flavor.

Comment: Thanks again inhan.. TBH: I was not sure what dw was using so I was trying to find out ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

Replace `<input(\s+\w+="(.*?)")*\s+id="(.+?)"(\s+\w+="(.*?)")* />`
With **[$3,Form]**